# Meaning of “Post-30 Seconds to Mars Jared Leto”

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Hollywood has a richly embarrassing history of mishaps, and one of the most egregious has got to be turning Post-30 Seconds to Mars Jared Leto into Oscar Winner Jared Leto in 2014."

I don't understand what "Post-30 Seconds to Mars Jared Leto" means. I know that Jared is an actor and I know that *post* sometimes refers to things that are already done or in the past, but it doesn't quite make sense in this case.

The sentence right after is

> The award, a prestigious accolade for a terribly miscast and terribly acted role in Dallas Buyers Club​, came to serve as an unneeded boost of confidence and a false sense of invincibility for Leto’s rejuvenated brand of trolling—one in a similar, but much more exaggerated, vein as post-Oscar winning Cuba Gooding Jr., who’s been spending his downtime eating cell phones in da club, or Gwyneth Paltrow, who’s casually been recommending $15,000 dildos on her lifestyle blog.

I don't quite understand "brand of trolling" although I knows that *trolling* sometimes means beings a prick or something. And what does "one" refer or link to?

Comment: [Thirty Seconds to Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Seconds_to_Mars) is his band's name...

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.

Answer (score 1):

Jared Leto was the lead singer in '30 Seconds to Mars'.

It implies that the leap from his singing career to being an Oscar winner falls into the category of "richly embarrassing history" in Hollywood.  Egregiously so.

Comment: May I ask why the sentence is framed as "one of the most egregious" which sounds kind of weird to me since I am used to people saying "one of the something(plural)

Comment: "Of all the performances at the show, one of the most awful was the jug band."  "Of all of the lights at the light show, one of the most colorful was the red and green laser blast".  In this case, rewrite: "One of the most egregious mishaps in Hollywood's richly embarrassing history has got to be Jared Leto going from singer to Oscar winner."

Comment: @HUN - The entire statement you quoted is quite hateful (I don't know if this is obvious to you or not). Whether the actors cited deserve such scorn is irrelevant; the author of the quote has demeaned himself (or herself) by using such language. This is not the type of writing you should emulate.

Comment: @MarkHubbard - I don't think that really answers the question at all.  Whether the writing is polite or not isn't relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: @JesseWilliams - I completely agree with with you. You already have done a fine job of answering his question, both in your answer and in your subsequent comment. But if HUN is learning English, I wanted to point out the implications of the quotation he was having trouble understanding; hence my comment (instead of another answer). Thank you for your measured and non-judgemental answer and comment. +1

Comment: Agreed - that's a fair way to look at it!  :)

Comment: @HUN: To answer your question with an explanation rather than a string of examples: the confusion is between actual nouns, and adjectives used for nouns. You're correct in thinking that "one of" should be followed by a plural, since the prepositional phrase is speaking of 1 element from a group of more than 1 element. If nouns are used, it looks plural, but using an adjective ("the most egregious") means it doesn't look plural - even though it is, because we don't inflect adjectives like that. You could read it more fully as "one of the most egregious mishaps etc."

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand what "Post-30 Seconds to Mars Jared Leto" means.

This is an understandably confusing line. Even I, a native speaker, had to read it a few times to understand the sense of it. It might have been more helpfully written as "Post-*'30 Seconds to Mars'* Jared Leto."

What's going on grammatically is that Jared Leto is a person, that this author put a compound adjective in front of his name in the form of "post-[something]," and then the [something] was four distinct, mostly capitalized words that overwhelmed Leto's actual name.